# internally repost the form after post -spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I have a method `aMethod()` in controller "A" which displays html via ajax AND IS POST BINDED.
now I want to call this method after post of another method in other controller "B". I mean I need to re-post after post. And I want to handle it internally so that user dosn't feels that form is posted twice

for GET rendering I can do

`redirect:/persons`

what to do for POST ??

Comment: You could just call your other method with the arguments it needs. Inside your first POST method, `return secondPostMethod(args)`. You will get the logic of the second POST without actually making a second HTTP request. This obviously won't trigger any interceptors or filters.

Comment: but that is in another controller, for that I need to create instance of controller "A" . AND if I use new A() , then my autowired binded services wont work. Is am wrong somewhere??

Comment: You can `@Autowired` any `@Controller` class instance into any other `@Controller`. You can then call your method on that autowired instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have all the data you need to call `aMethod` server-side when the method in controller "B" is called, just inject a reference to controller "A" into controller "B" and call `aMethod` and the end of the method in controller "B".

```
@Controller 
public class ControllerB {
    @Autowired
    private ControllerA controllerA;

    ....
    public Object bMethod() {
        // do whatever you need to here
        return controllerA.aMethod();
    }
```